# Monorepo with spring-boot 1,x, 2.x and 3.x modules

Tags: spring-boot, maven, monorepo

I'm consolidating many maven based spring-boot projects into a monorepo. Those projects are based on different spring boot versions (most of them 1.x, one 2.x and a 3.x).
All project compile with java 17 (provided that the release property in each pom.xml drive the correct java release to be used).

The problem is:

- if the parent pom as `<parent>` spring-boot-starter-parent:1.55.22-RELEASE the spring boot 3.x module does not compile (even if in it's own `pom.xml` i declare in `<dependencyManagement>` the spring-boot-dependencies:3.1.2)
- if the parent pom has no parent it self and each pom declare it's own `<dependencyManagement>` spring-boot-dependencies the resulting wars and jars aren't executable and the MANIFEST does not declare the necessary info

Which strategy do you suggest?

1. Multiple monorepos `<sic>`
2. Multiple parent (one per spring version)
3. ...